# Dictionary with arrays of keys and values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is in regards to javascript or jQuery, whichever will get the job done better.

What I want to do is create an object similar to the following:

```
var prodItems = [
    {
        "product": "prod1",
        "item": ["prod1Item1", "prod1Item2"]
    },
    {
        "product": "prod2",
        "item": ["prod2Item1", "prod2Item2", "prod2Item3", "prod2Item4"]
    }
];
```

with this I can access the members like this:

```
prodItems[1]["product"] is "prod2"

prodItems[1]["item"][0] is "prod2Item1"
```

I would like to create this list dynamically and I am stumbling with the syntax, something like:

```
var menuItems;
menuItems.product[0] = "prod1";
menuItems.product[0].item[0] = "prod1Item1";
```

Can someone please give me some guidance on how I can do this?

Edit, i want to create a function with something like

```
returnDict("prod2", "prod2Item3")
```

this will rearrange it like so:

```
 prodItems = [
    {
        "product": "prod2",
        "item": ["prod2Item3", "prod2Item1", "prod2Item2", "prod2Item4"]
    },
    {
        "product": "prod1",
        "item": ["prod1Item1", "prod2Item2"]

    }
];
```

Comment: It's not very clear how you're going to construct such an object dynamically? Where is the data you're using coming from, and what does it look like ?

Comment: the data is actually going to come from the first one. I will create the prodItems one exactly like I have it in the question, but I want to create a second one dynamically. The second one could have the items in a different order, however which is why I want to make it dynamically.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but you can make a copy of the first one with `prodItems.slice()` as it's an array, and you can rearrange the inner arrays with something like `prodItems[0].item.sort(function(a,b) {...})`

Comment: see my edit for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "guidance" on constructing the object would be to avoid this style of inserting each string separately:

```
menuItems.product[0].product = "prod1";
menuItems.product[0].item[0] = "prod1Item1";
```

because this involves a lot of writing the same thing over and over, which is more error-prone and less readable/maintainable. I would prefer inserting more coarse-grained objects:

```
menuItems.product[0] = {
    product: "prod1",
    item: ["prod1Item1"];
}
```

Edit: Your edit is asking a completely different question, but it sounds like what you want to do is sort the elements of prodItems based on their "product" properties, then do the same thing for the "items" array inside the elements.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to use Array.sort() with a custom comparison function that returns -1 on the element you want to see at the top. Something like this (hastily written and untested):

```
function returnDict(product, item) {
    prodItems = prodItems.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.product === product) {
            return -1;
        } else if(b.product === product) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    prodItems[0].items = prodItems[0].items.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a === item) {
            return -1;
        } else if(b === item) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return prodItems;
}
```

Comment: I am not the best at wording questions, I'll admit. Thank you for your effort for this it has got me off to a good start, and is a lot more efficient that the multiple loops I attempted to use to do this.

Comment: you did more than help. It looks like you wrote the whole thing for me. I thought I would have to change it a bit, but damn it looks like it works right out of the box. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

```
var menuItems = [];
menuItems.push({product:"prod1",item:[]})
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product1Item1")
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product1Item2")
menuItems.push({product:"prod2",item:[]})
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product2Item1")
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product2Item2")
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product2Item3")
menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product2Item4")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for what I asked. I would select it as the answer, however I think Ixrec's answer is a better approach than what I was doing in the first place.

Comment: I actually agree, NiteTrip. My code is not practical, except if you would package `menuItems[menuItems.length-1].item.push("product1Item1")` in a `function pushItemToLastProduct(item)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var prodItems = [
    {
        "product": "prod1",
        "item": ["prod1Item1", "prod2Item2"]
    },
    {
        "product": "prod2",
        "item": ["prod2Item1", "prod2Item2", "prod2Item3", "prod2Item4"]
    }
];

alert(prodItems[0].product);

for(var i = 0; i < prodItems.length; i++) {
   alert(prodItems[i].product);
}
```

Comment: I'm loving this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see your question has been answered, but I want to suggest a small improvement to keep your code more DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself). You can use a simple function that will save you some extra typing when adding new objects.

```
var prodItems=[];

function addProduct(productName, items){
    var product={
        product: productName,
        items: items
    };
    prodItems.push(product);
};

//sample use
addProduct("prod2",["prod2Item3", "prod2Item1", "prod2Item2", "prod2Item4"])
```

This will definitely also become more flexible if you need to change the object structure at some later point.